# Mongoose debug writes to STDERR?

Tags: debugging, mongoose, stdout, stderr

Does anyone know / have info about why mongoose writes its debug log to stderr? Is there anyway to write it to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug option accepts a function instead of a boolean:

```
mongoose.set("debug", function (collection, method, paramA, paramB, paramC) {

    console.log(collection)
    console.log(method)
    console.log(paramA)
    console.log(paramB)
    console.log(paramC)
})
```

The reason I put `paramA, paramB, paramC` is because the arguments are dependent upon the method and options being used:

```
Person.create({firstName: "john"}, callback)
// people
// insert
// {firstName: "john"}
// undefined
// undefined

Person.update({firstName: "john"}, {lastName: "doe"}, {new: true}, callback);
// people
// update
// {firstName: "john"}
// {$set: {lastName: "doe"}}
// {new: true}

Person.find({firstName: "john"}, callback);
// people
// find
// {firstName: "john"}
// undefined
// undefined

Person.find({firstName: "john"}, {limit: 1}, callback);
// people
// find
// {firstName: "john"}
// {limit: 1}
// undefined
```

The info being logged is the *Mongodb* input, not the *Mongoose* input.  You can see this in the `update()` method, `paramB` comes out as `{$set: {lastName: "doe"}}`. Behind the scenes, Mongoose converts updates to use `$set`, which is why that is logged.

From this, you can easily just format it however you want and `process.stdout.write()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Using the fact that 'debug' is responsible for producing the log, I found this line in mongoose/lib/collection.js:          

console.error('\x1B[0;36mMongoose:\x1B[0m %s.%s(%s) %s %s %s', self.name, i, print(args[0]), print(args[1]), print(args[2]), print(args[3]))